# Function for a specific numeric sequence without any parameters

Tags: c++, algorithm, function

I got an university task which i am totally stuck on. Normally I wouldn't post about it here, but none of my colleagues has any idea how to solve it.
The Task:

Design an algorithm "NEXT", which delivers the subsequent value of the numeric sequence  {0,3,5,6,9,10,12,15,18,20,21,...} as function value whenever it is called. The algorithm must not use parameters or global variables or vectors.

I have to implement it in C++ (which shouldn't be too much of an issue for me). I just have no idea how. I can't find any form of rule for the number sequence. And i am kinda stuck on the part where i have to return the next value of the sequence without giving any parameters to the function.

It would be awesome if someone could help me out here :)

(FYI, i had to translate the task and i hope I didn't make any critical Errors... Here it is again in the original languge german:
Entwerfen Sie einen Algorithmus N E X T, der bei jedem Aufruf den
jeweils nachsten Wert der Folge {0,3,5,6,9,10,12,15,18,20,21,...} als Funktionswert liefert.
Der Algorithmus darf weder Parameter haben noch globale Variablen oder Vektoren verwenden.)

Comment: Hint: read up on function local static variables.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) will do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence consists in all multiples of 3 or 5, in increasing order.

Answer (score 2):

See below for the initial version of this answer. Though, rici made me realize that I made a mistake, probably the same mistake you made: I interpreted the task to write a plain function. However, being asked to write an algorithm does not mean that it must be a plain function only. Even if you want to write something that can be called, callables can have state. And if the callable is not a plain function then there are solutions that are much cleaner than a function local static variable as it was my first idea when writing this answer initially.

A callable can be a functor. An instance of a class with a call operator. I will stay with the initial example of a simple counter and leave the actual implementation of the algorithm to you:

```
#include <iostream>

struct counter {
    int value;
    int operator()() {
        ++value;
        return value;
    }
};

int main() {
    counter c1{};
    std::cout << c1() << "\n";
    std::cout << c1() << "\n";
    counter c2{42};
    std::cout << c2() << "\n";
    std::cout << c2() << "\n";
}
```

Compared to the function local static variable this has the benefit of being reusable. When you want to count again from the beginning you can create a fresh `counter`.

---

The initial version of the answer:

As mentioned in a comment, this task is probably meant to teach you about function local static variables. A simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

int count() { 
    static int i = 0;
    ++i;
    return i;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << count() << "\n";
    std::cout << count() << "\n";
    std::cout << count() << "\n";
}
```

`i` is initialized only on the first call and retains its value between function calls, ie the returned values differs by `1` for each call.

Whether function local static variables are any better than global variables in general is a matter of opinion. They make the function useable only for a specific scenario. Anyhow there are situations where a function local static variable is just the right tool so you should learn about them (but not confuse them with a goto solution for any case where a callable needs some state).

Comment: Static globals and static locals aren't the only two possibilities, since this is C++. I don't see where the task descriptions prohibits constructing a class object with instance variables to record the state. An object would be superior to local static variables in almost any scenario, and it's a much better technique to learn. IMHO. (I suppose that it could be argued that `this` is an implicit parameter, which is certainly true. But then, static locals are in a certain sense an implicit vector, no?)

Comment: @rici only now I noticed that the only place where OP mentions a function is when they say "i have to return the next value of the sequence without giving any parameters to the function." but thats the description of their problem, it does not appear in the task description. You are absolutely right, good catch

Comment: @rici I tried to fix the answer. Actually I don't like it that much now, but I wanted to keep both.

Answer (score 0):

If your professor prefers compact but unreadable code over the readable one they may like this:

```
int NEXT()
{
    static int c3 = 0, c5 = 0;
    int v3 = c3 * 3, v5 = c5 * 5;
    return v3 == v5 ? c3++, c5++, v3 : v3 < v5 ? c3++, v3 : c5++, v5;
}
```